# How to create appengine flexible runtime in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I installed latest google cloud sdk and app-engine-java component.

In eclipse I installed google cloud tools and specified my google-cloud-sdk installation in eclipse.

Elipse itself created for me App Engine Standard Runtime in Server runtime environments.

But I want App Engine Flexible Runtime.

How to create this runtime in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse) has supported  the App Engine flexible environment since June (v1.2.0).  Please try *Help > Check for Updates* and make sure you're running the latest version.

CT4E offers a new project wizard with *File > New > Google > Google App Engine Flexible Java Project* (also available from the Google toolbar). You can debug your app locally using the [Eclipse Jetty plugin](https://eclipse-jetty.github.io/).  You can deploy your app from the IDE too.